# Visual Studio Team Services - release definition - run task (PowerShell) as admin

Tags: powershell, continuous-integration, uac, continuous-deployment, azure-devops

In VSTS I have a release definition, which needs to run a PowerShell script as administrator.

The release agent is configured to run as an account, which is a local administrator and has the required permissions, but UAC is restricting those permissions, unless PowerShell is executed "as administrator".

Can I run PS as admin from VSTS without disabling UAC completely on the server?

Comment: What action in your power-shell script  need the administrator permission? I have a power-shell script to add and update the registry under HKLM. It can be run successfully on my build agent when the agent is run with an administrator account.

Comment: I am running the script as SPFarm account and it is retracting/deploying WSP solutions into a SharePoint farm. The script works when executing as built-in administrator, but doesn't work for any other account, even though the permissions are the same. I think that's because UAC is disabled for built-in admin account, but not for any other.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to do that using PS task. Can you try "Run PS on target servers" and provide admin creds. You will need to provide the machine name of the agent (so this is not ideal) as an input to the task. That might not require UAC. We will file this as a feature request.

Comment: "Run PS on target server" is not ideal. As a workaround I also considered executing an elevated task, which would have to be pre-defined on the server, but eventually re-configured the agent to run as a built-in administrator, which can bypass UAC. Again, not ideal, as I would prefer to use another, more restricted account, so yes - definitely a feature worth building for one of the next releases of VSTS.

Comment: do you know if this ever implemented? I'm looking for a task that will let me run as admin my power-shell script. the task "Powershell on remote machines" is not applicable in my case as I need to put inline script not a path to the file. because targeted machine do not contain that script.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem. To fix it I did this (YMMV):

1. I uninstalled the Azure DevOps agent
2. Verified that the agent user was an admin
3. Reinstalled the Azure DevOps agent

When I originally installed the agent, the user the agent was running as was not an admin (I added that user to the Builtin\Administrators group after I installed the agent).  I'm not sure if that caused a problem, but uninstalling/reinstalling solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that the Inline or Path options are the issue. Maybe installing an Agent in the Deployment Environment Machine, assigning in the installation process the credentials of a user you are sure has administrative privileges on the SharePoint farm could help you. Then in VSTS verify that the agent is Online and working in the Deployment Group Section.

Answer (score -1):

We got around not being able to use elevated Powershell commands by creating a light .Netcore Worker service with http request capability running in an elevated service privilege state. You can send a **Invoke-RestMethod** command from a regular Powershell YML task and it will trigger your custom logic on the other end of the ASP controller. We use it to remove Appx packages before re-installing for our Unit tests. The repo is located at, [AzureAdmin](https://github.com/sofdigital/AzureAdmin)